Amplify/Cognito Authenticator not pulling SignupAttributes
I'm relatively new to Amplify and I'm making use of their built in ui component for authentication to a Cognito pool.
I've set it up that when signing up they can provide a username and a preferred_username (based on docs here), however when I go to make user of either of those attributes (for when writing to my dynamo table) nothing is available. I know some attributes like, address, gender, locale, picture, updated_at, and zoneinfo aren't rendered, but to my understanding username and preferred_username shouldn't be an issue, correct??
Below is my implementation of the component itself within my App.vue file.
<Authenticator :login-mechanisms="['username']" :sign-up-attributes="['username', 'preferred_username'] "
    v-slot="{ user, signOut }">
    <template v-if="user">
      <div class="min-h-screen bg-gray-50 p-8 flex flex-col items-center" @click="handleClickOutside">
        <h1 class="text-4xl font-bold text-center text-gray-800 mb-8 medievalsharp-regular">
          Talisman Victory Tracker
        </h1>

        <p class="text-lg text-gray-600 mb-4">
          Welcome, <strong>{{ user || 'Player' }}</strong>! 
          <!-- Your email: <em>{{ user.attributes.email }}</em> -->
        </p>

        <div class="grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 gap-12 max-w-5xl">
          <CharacterCard
            v-for="(character, index) in characters"
            :key="character.name"
            :character="character"
            :isFlipped="flippedCardIndex === index"
            @log-win="showWinModal"
            @flip-card="flipCard(index)"
            class="medievalsharp-regular flex justify-center items-center"
          />
        </div>

        <WinModal 
          v-if="isModalVisible"
          :visible="isModalVisible"
          :winDetails="currentWinDetails"
          @close="isModalVisible = false"
          
        />

        <button @click="signOut" class="mt-4 bg-red-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded">
          Sign Out
        </button>
      </div>
    </template>
  </Authenticator>

I'm able to successfully create a user, sign-in, and authenticate, but when I pull back the user object, the only bit of data that's returned in the user object is the following... Am I missing something?
{ 
  "username": "<randomly_gereated_id>", 
  "userId": "<another_randomly_generated_id>", 
  "signInDetails": {
     "loginId": "<my_email>", 
     "authFlowType": "USER_SRP_AUTH" 
   } 
}

